# Do I have to disable color profiles in Gnome when running dispcal

Tags: gnome, colors, color-profiles

I am currently trying to calibrate my monitor using ArgyllCMS' `dispcal`:

```
dispcal -v -o outfile
```

However my Gnome color management tool has already loaded some generic profile for my monitor. Do I have to disable that profile before calibration or does the appearing calibration pattern bypass any profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that dispcal is automatically deactivating all color profiles during the calibration process.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: But it **is** the answer.